# How to add sub label to an image to perform object recognition using YOLO?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection, object-recognition, yolov4

Please help . I have images of a car, Trucks, bikes. I want to train a YOLO or object detection model  on it which can output the car_owner, truck_owner, car_model, truck_model, truck_km, car_km etc. But What I know is we can label the images for YOLO taking just one part of information as label in object detection models. Like We can annotate car's image, truck's image as object within an image and it becomes labels to train the model. But I want my model to output these above mentioned information like owner, model, km etc.

How to do this?

Is there any tool to label the images with information and train YOLO or any other model? (Except Image labeler from Matlab)